# How to add Fragments in ViewPager from getView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

Can any one help me , How to add ViewPager using FragmentStatePageAdapter in getView.

I am using https://github.com/Diolor/Swipecards library . My requirement is to add viewpager at every card from using FrgamentStatePageAdapter. But after implementing ViewPager only first item contains ViewPager other cards is not accepting Viewpager .

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

In my case am not using any library, this is how I use it.

```
private static final int NUM_PAGES = NUMBER OF PAGES I NEED;

private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
        public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ScreenSlidePageFragment.create(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_PAGES;
        }
    }
```

The NUM_PAGES determines the number of pages we need. Please check your code for that.

In the Adapter,

```
 public static ScreenSlidePageFragment create(int pageNumber) {
        ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_PAGE, pageNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public ScreenSlidePageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mPageNumber = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Hi Bro , We have already added FragmentStatePageAdapter so many times . But not in ListView , means we have to create viewpager in getView, By this we will not get view pager at every item .
Thanks for your reply.